# How can I create a custom relay for modifying email content and recipients in postfix and node.js?

Tags: node.js, email, postfix-mta, mtu, mta

I want to create a custom relay before forwarding to gmail smtp using postfix and nodejs

I want to develop a serer that modify the mail content and recipients and add tractable link that specifies how many time user opened the mail and opened the link which are in mails.

but main motto is to modify the content using post fix and node.

I have did setup , created a file that modify the code but not working so I'm here
can you please suggest me something.

Thanks in advance

1. Setup the post fix
2. modify the main.cf,master.cf file also added modify data function file path in to mentioned files as per docs also I get help form chat GPT.
3. Expectation is like post fix will change the content and recipients details , and mail should be tractable.